# Will iOS load the maps data in MKMapView while there is no network connectivity

Tags: iphone, ios

I use MKMapView for location base development, then i found that the mapView just show some gray grids in the screen while no network connectivity, so my question is that: do MKMapview load maps data while offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** You need an active internet connection to view Map data. However, some tiles are cached but those tiles still need to have been downloaded at some point.

Also, you will not be able to search locations within those tiles and distance / coordinate data may not be accurate either.